# How to achieve similar structure to Eloquent's eager loading but with Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 3 different tables.
`Table1` is the "main" table with primary `id` key.

`Table2` and `Table3` use `Table1` id as foreign key `table_1_id`

Let's say I have some query from Table 1:

```
Table1::where(...)->where(...)->get();
```

which gives me 100 results.

Then I want to get all the data from `Table2` and `Table3` with the IDs of Table1, but still have 100 results, so a structure similar to Eloquents eager loading when it attaches the relationship results to the original Model result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [table2_data] => Array ( <table2_rows_array that matches id1> )
            [table3_data] => Array ( <table3_rows_array that matches id1> )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [table2_data] => Array ( <table2_rows_array that matches id2> )
            [table3_data] => Array ( <table3_rows_array that matches id2> )
        )
    ...
    ...
    [100] => Array
        (
            [table2_data] => Array ( <table2_rows_array that matches id100> )
            [table3_data] => Array ( <table3_rows_array that matches id100> )
        )
)
```

Right now I am doing separate queries with `whereIn` but still it is not the same structure and I need to manipulate it with PHP

Comment: This is how relationships in laravel works. As I understood from your question, you have table1, table2 with table1_id column and table3 with table1_id. Am I right?

Comment: yes exactly but I have an issue in this part of code where I can't use relationships

Comment: You can use join for that. So for your query, you'll have something like this: ``DB::table("table1")->join("table2", "table1.id", "=", "table2.table1_id")->join("table3", "table1.id", "=", "table3.table1_id")->get()``. I guess this is what you want.

Comment: Yes this is what I am doing, but then I do a `foreach` loop on the table1 unique results, but how can I then display only what belongs to that table rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to eager load relationship , you have to :

1. get the base table data in this case `table1` and create a
   collection for it
2. create an array with the table1 data ids
3. get related tables where the relationship column `table1_id` is in the ids array
4. loop over each **element** of the first table1 collection and add an attribute for each related table with the related data as a value where `table1_id` equal to the current **element** `id`

```
$table1 = DB::table('table1')->select('*')->get();

$table1_ids = $table1->pluck('id')->all();

$table2 = DB::table('table1')->select('*')->whereIn('table1_id', $table1_ids)->get();
$table3 = DB::table('table1')->select('*')->whereIn('table1_id', $table1_ids)->get();
$table4 = DB::table('table1')->select('*')->whereIn('table1_id', $table1_ids)->get();

foreach($table1 as $el){
    $el->table2data = $table2->where('table1_id',$el->id);
    $el->table3data = $table3->where('table1_id',$el->id);
    $el->table4data = $table4->where('table1_id',$el->id);
}
```

#### Note That :

- for the foreach we looped over a collection and we used the `where()` of the `collection` so no other query was made ! :D
- instead of N+1 queries we used a query to get the main model and then a query to get each related model, in this case, a total of **4 queries**, which is independent of the data count `the N`

#### Result

one single collection with all table1 data and in each element fo this collection you ll have 3 attribute for each relation (table2_data, table3_data, table4_data..) with the element related data.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you man! Btw, I checked and it's working, but I believe that using joins can be faster because imagine I need to iterate over thousands of rows. I think that even though the `where()` belongs to the `collection`, it's still a heavy method when it's done a lot of times right?

Comment: @B.DLiroy so using joins will give you a single collection with all results you ll have to filter it using a loop right ? , so in any way, you have to use some filtering .
the where() method is like a native array search , and this translates to how eager loading works so i think it should be the most efficient solution